# Culture fair question - boxes, angles, lines

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

[image]

**Select the correct choice from the bottom 6 options to fill the final box above the horizontal line.**

I stumbled upon this seemingly difficult question while doing a Mensa practice test. I have since been trying to figure it out but I can't. I am calling it seemingly difficult because these questions always appear to be difficult, until you come up or are provided with, their simple and elegant answer.

Source: This question is found on the old [Mensa Norway IQ test](https://test.mensa.no), but now this question is found on the [Mensa Finland IQ test](https://www.mensa.fi/iq/index_2.html)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It is

> the bottom right one.

Because

> In each column, flip the top image over the horizontal axis. Overlay the second image; where *both* images have lines, erase the line. You end up with the third image.

Answer (score -3):

I think it’s the top middle one. On the question the top rows are the completed picture.The bottom and middle rows are combined to make the top picture. The dotted lines means that part will be filled in by the other picture. When you combine the pictures you also get rid of all the parts that they both have in common.

Comment: If you were right with how you have explained it, the top right image would have to be missing the small vertical line on the right.